# Cannot get Android drivers to install on LG Thrill

Tags: usb, windows, usb-drivers, lg-thrill

I've Googled everything I could think of and I can't get this to work.

I'm trying to help someone set up his Android phone - an LG Thrill 4G - to connect to his PC so he can text from his computer, back up his contacts, etc.  I downloaded and installed the SDK.  I used the SDK manager to install more stuff, including the Google USB driver.  I can see the usb_driver folder in the Android SDK extras folder, and I can see .dll files inside (if I remember correctly).  I've set the phone to have whatever USB box checked.  And, of course, I went to the Device Manager (he's got Windows 7), right-clicked the phone, and tried finding drivers online and finding them on the computer.  No dice.

Something online said I should run the dpinst.exe file and that it should be in the usb_driver folder.  It isn't.  Should this exist?  Is there another way to get the driver to install?  Should I take another route altogether?  What am I missing?

Comment: Have you checked to see if LG provides any kind of drivers or other software for the phone? Some manufacturers do, and they tend to work best in my experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LG's site is terrible so it took me a while to find, but you can get the drivers for the Thrill from here: http://www.lg.com/us/support-mobile/lg-P925

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a dream. I did have to go to Computer->Manage again and right-click on the device to update the driver, but after that it worked beautifully.  Thanks!